# Lisp - Flag(bandera) don't funtion

Tags: loops, common-lisp, conditional-statements, palindrome, clisp

I'm trying to write a function to determine whether a word is palindrome or not. I make this but it always returns "Is not a palindrome". I don't know what is happening.

```
(defun palindromo (X)
    (setq i 0)
    (setq j (- (length X) 1))
    (setq bandera 0)
    (loop while (< j i)
        do
        (when (char= (char X i) (char X j))
            (+ i 1)
            (- j 1)
            (setq bandera 1))
        (unless (char/= (char X i) (char X j))
            (setq bandera 0)

        )
    )
    (cond
    ((equal 0 bandera) (write "Is not a palindrome"))
    ((equal 1 bandera) (write "Is a palindrome"))
    )   
)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Loop problem

Your loop termination test is `while (< j i)`, but you previously set  `i` and `j` to respectively the index of the first and last character. That means that `(<= i j)`. You never execute the body of the loop, and `bandera` is never modified from its initial value, 0.

#### Infinite loop problem

But suppose you fix your test so that it becomes `(< i j)`, then your loop becomes an infinite loop, because you *never* mutates either `i` nor `j` in the body of your loop. The two expressions `(+ i 1)` and `(- j 1)` only computes the next indices, but do not change existing bindings. You would have to use `setq`, just as you did above.

#### Invalid use of SETQ

By the way, you cannot introduce variables with `setq`: it is undefined what happens when trying to set a variable that is not defined. You can introduce global variables with `defvar`, `defparameter`, and local variables with, among others, `let`, `let*` and the loop keyword `with`.

I assume your Common Lisp implementation implicitly defined global variables when you executed or compiled `(setq i 0)` and other assignments. But this is far from ideal since now your function depends on the global state and is not reentrant. If you called `palindromo` from different threads, all global variables would be modified concurrently, which would give incorrect results. Better use local variables.

#### Boolean logic

Do not use `0` and `1` for your flag, Lisp uses  `nil` as false and everything else as true for its boolean operators.

#### Confusing tests

In the loop body, you first write:

```
 (when (char= (char X i) (char X j)) ...)
```

Then you write:

```
 (unless (char/= (char X i) (char X j)) ...)
```

Both test the same thing, and the second one involves a double-negation (*unless not equal*), which is hard to read.

#### Style

- You generally do not want to print things from utility functions.
  You should probably only return a boolean result.
- The name of `X` is a little bit unclear, I'd would have used `string`.
- Try to use the conventional way of formatting your Lisp code. It helps to use an editor which auto-indents your code (e.g. Emacs). Also, do not leave dangling parentheses on their own lines.

#### Rewrite

```
(defun palindromep (string)
  (loop with max = (1- (length string))
        for i from 0
        for j downfrom max
        while (< i j)
        always (char= (char string i)
                      (char string j))))
```

- I added a `p` to `palindrome` by convention, because it is a predicate.
- The `with max = ...` in the loop defines a loop variable which holds the index of the last character (or -1 if `string` is empty).
- `i` is a loop variable which increments, starting from 0
- `j` is a loop variable which decrements, starting from max
- the `while`is a termination test
- `always` evaluates a form at each execution of the loop, and check whether it is always true (non-nil).

Comment: I'm so thankful with you @coredump! I appreciate the time that you take for explain all my errors or not very good practices. I understood all that you wrote. Thank you again! Greetings! :)

Comment: @CinthiaLima No problem, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no externally defined loop is needed for finding out, whether a string is palindromic or not. [ Remark: well, I thought that in the beginning. But as @coredump and @jkiiski pointed out, the `reverse` function slows down the procedure, since it copies the entire string once. ]

Use:

```
(defun palindromep (s)
  (string= s (reverse s)))
```

[ This function will be way more efficient than your code
and it returns `T` if s is palindromic, else `NIL`.] (Not true, it only saves you writing effort, but it is less efficient than the procedure using `loop`.)

A verbose version would be:

```
(defun palindromep (s)
   (let ((result (string= s (reverse s))))
     (write (if result
                "Is a palindrome"
                "Is not a palindrome"))
     result))
```

Writes the answer you wish but returns `T` or `NIL`.

The naming convention for a test function returning `T` or `NIL` is to end the name with `p` for 'predicate'.

**The reverse function is less performant than the while loop suggested by @coredump**

This was my beginner attempt to test the speed [not recommendable]:

```
;; Improved loop version by @coredump:

(defun palindromep-loop (string)
  (loop with max = (1- (length string))
        for i from 0
        for j downfrom max
        while (< i j)
        always (char= (char string i)
                      (char string j))))

;; the solution with reverse
(defun palindromep (s)
  (string= s (reverse s)))

;; the test functions test over and over the same string "abcdefggfedcba"
;; 10000 times over and over again 
;; I did the repeats so that the measuring comes at least to the milliseconds
;; range ... (but it was too few repeats still. See below.)

(defun test-palindrome-loop ()
  (loop repeat 10000
        do (palindromep-loop "abcdefggfedcba")))

(time (test-palindrome-loop))

(defun test-palindrome-p ()
  (loop repeat 10000
        do (palindromep "abcdefggfedcba")))

(time (test-palindrome-p))

;; run on SBCL
[55]> (time (test-palindrome-loop))
Real time: 0.152438 sec.
Run time: 0.152 sec.
Space: 0 Bytes
NIL
[56]> (time (test-palindrome-p))
Real time: 0.019284 sec.
Run time: 0.02 sec.
Space: 240000 Bytes
NIL

;; note: this is the worst case that the string is a palindrome
;; for `palindrome-p` it would break much earlier when a string is 
;; not a palindrome!
```

And this is @coredump's attempt to test the speed of the functions:

```
(lisp-implementation-type)
"SBCL"

(lisp-implementation-version)
"1.4.0.75.release.1710-6a36da1"

(machine-type)
"X86-64"

(defun palindromep-loop (string)
  (loop with max = (1- (length string))
        for i from 0
        for j downfrom max
        while (< i j)
        always (char= (char string i)
                      (char string j))))

(defun palindromep (s)
  (string= s (reverse s)))

(defun test-palindrome-loop (s)
  (sb-ext:gc :full t)
  (time
   (loop repeat 10000000
         do (palindromep-loop s))))

(defun test-palindrome-p (s)
  (sb-ext:gc :full t)
  (time
   (loop repeat 10000000
         do (palindromep s))))

(defun rand-char ()
  (code-char
   (+ #.(char-code #\a)
      (random #.(- (char-code #\z) (char-code #\a))))))

(defun generate-palindrome (n &optional oddp)
  (let ((left (coerce (loop repeat n collect (rand-char)) 'string)))
    (concatenate 'string
                 left
                 (and oddp (list (rand-char)))
                 (reverse left))))

(let ((s (generate-palindrome 20)))
  (test-palindrome-p s)
  (test-palindrome-loop s))

Evaluation took:
  4.093 seconds of real time
  4.100000 seconds of total run time (4.068000 user, 0.032000 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.124 seconds GC time, and 3.976 seconds non-GC time. ]
  100.17% CPU
  9,800,692,770 processor cycles
  1,919,983,328 bytes consed

Evaluation took:
  2.353 seconds of real time
  2.352000 seconds of total run time (2.352000 user, 0.000000 system)
  99.96% CPU
  5,633,385,408 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

What I have learned from that:
- Test more rigorously, repeat as often as necessary (range of seconds)
- do random generation and then test in parallel

Thank you very much for the nice example @coredump! And for the remark @jkiiski!

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"?

Comment: I guess that `string=`, since it is implemented as basic CL function, will be programmed in a way that it will stop when encountering first mismatch and return NIL, thus the maximum number of comparisons performed is the number of elements in the list. The `reverse` and the `string=` traverses the list only maximum 2 times and the number of tests is minimized. The `while` loop in the question - after correction of all mistakes will do for sure more for each query.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim `REVERSE` copies the entire string, which will be a lot less efficient than just looping with two indices and exiting at the first mismatch.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim Thank for reply! I made that solution too, but i make this other because i want to work in this way for know how to use the loop, condition, etc for begin understand CLisp.

Comment: @jkiiski: Still the loop version needs more steps and function calls/testings. I added a very primitive time testing at the lower section of my answer.

Comment: @Cinthia Lima - all right - I am learning looping, too :) - it is essential for becoming fluent in Lisp, I think :) .

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim The loop version needs less tests. `STRING=` will, in worst case, test each letter while the loop version can stop when the two indices cross (so it only tests half of the string against the other half)

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim If I time them on my machine, the loop version takes only half as long and half as many cycles as the reversing version. You probably got different results because the number of repetitions is so low that the result is practically random. Try changing the repetitions from `10000` to `100000000` and the difference should become much clearer.

Comment: With only 10000 iteration I get around 1ms which is not precise enough. I tried with longer palindromes (non-constant ones), more repetitions and by calling the gc before tests: https://pastebin.com/raw/qCb5PEuh

Comment: @jkiiski: True, I chose too short cycles (and I should generate it randomly) my test was not good. You are right `reverse` makes it slow.

Comment: @coredump: Thank you for the nice example! I am pretty new with such kind of testing yet. I will apply testing more rigorously in future. Thank you!

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim No problem, it just seemed counter-intuitive to me. Sometimes compilers do weird things (e.g. C compilers), so I wouldn't be completely surprised if your test with a constant string was compiled to a constant expression in some cases, for example. Also, statistics are hard.

Comment: @coredump: Thanks. Yes, when increasing number of my example - it still seemed to be a magnitude faster. Strange. But your code gives me too a clear advantage of your loop version.

Comment: so another facit of this story is: It is more than worth to learn looping in CL ;) .